# How to change the output form of result

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation

If you use *Mathematica* to do this integral:

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 - a^2), x]
```

you will get a uncommon function form like

> ```
> -(ArcTanh[x/a]/a)
> ```

Well, I don't like `ArcTanh`. And as we know the result should be $$\frac{1}{2a}\log\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|$$It's equal to the *Mathematica* result. But can I change the result of *Mathematica* into this form?

Comment: Try `TrigToExp[]`. But, I don't understand your objection to `ArcTanh[]`: I myself prefer it to [the long expression in terms of `Log[]`](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTanh/02/0001/).

Comment: @J.M. It's a trick for me.Thanks.